# How do I run pytest for one testcase in a Django app when I have been using "python manage.py test" all this time?

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

Django v2.2

I have been writing my test case for 2 years now this way:

```
from django.test import override_settings
from rest_framework.test import APIClient, APITestCase
from someapp.tests.factories import (
    OrganizationFactory,
)


class SomeTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.maxDiff = None
        self.organization = OrganizationFactory(name="ENP", domain="localhost")

    @override_settings(ALLOWED_HOSTS=["*"])
    def test_something(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

then I run

```
python manage.py test logical.path.to.SomeTestCase.test_something --keepdb
```

the `--keepdb` is to avoid thrashing the test database and rebuild from scratch

My `config.settings.test.py` is

```
"""
With these settings, tests run faster.
"""

from .base import *  # noqa
from .base import env

# GENERAL
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug
DEBUG = False
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secret-key
SECRET_KEY = env("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY", default="lKwzkRnq8dksTthPauE61WrNPVwA3HdnJtQ9HuIyCpBib5zCY06tFsD5TUpNlCnO")
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#test-runner
TEST_RUNNER = "django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner"

# CACHES
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#caches
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache", "LOCATION": ""
    }
}

# PASSWORDS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#password-hashers
PASSWORD_HASHERS = ["django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher"]

# TEMPLATES
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#templates
TEMPLATES[0]["OPTIONS"]["debug"] = DEBUG  # noqa F405
TEMPLATES[0]["OPTIONS"]["loaders"] = [  # noqa F405
    (
        "django.template.loaders.cached.Loader",
        [
            "django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader",
            "django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader",
        ],
    )
]

# EMAIL
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-backend
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend"
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-host
EMAIL_HOST = "localhost"
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-port
EMAIL_PORT = 1025

# Your stuff...
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `python manage.py test` command worked

Now i write a new test using pytest

```
import pytest

pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_pytest():

    assert True
```

Then I run `pytest logical.path.to.pytests.test_pytest`

It says the file cannot be found.

I checked my `base.py` and I did add `logical` as an app.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: have you tried `python manage.py test` ? In most of the cases, Django will auto-discover the test cases

Comment: `pytest logical/path/to/pytests.py::test_pytest`